# Is it possible to modify event data in public google calendar using only public key?

Tags: javascript, security, google-api, google-calendar-api

I use public google calendar in my demo application. And I specified calendar id and public key on my html page.

So, can anybody insert/update/delete my events using only public key? Or these operations are allowed only for authorized(through Auth2.0) users?

Comment: Have you considered testing it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I've embedded a calendar to html page(using code from calendar settings page) and I can't have modified anything. Also I've read [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) and it looks like I always should use authorization to modify events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

According to [events.delete](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) it is not possible to modify events without authorization.